# Slow query due sql count - how to improve?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i've got quite a problem with sql query - it's getting slower due more rows to check. Db is growing up fast... In slowlog from sql i get warning:

> ## Time: 161113 15:55:55
>
> ## User@Host: ....
>
> ## Query_time: 13.133105  Lock_time: 0.000487 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 91729

Query uses count and looks like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM `product_to_features` AS `product_to_feature` WHERE `id_feature_value` = 0 AND `id_product` IN (0, '20924', '20950', '20951', '21006', '21007', '21008', '21009', '21010', '21017', '21029', '21030', '21045', '21046', '21057', '21058', '21059', '21079', '21080', '21103', '21104', '21105', '21106', '21107', '21117', '21123', '21244', '21463', '21464', '21466', '21465', '21503', '21504', '21505', '21506', '21518', '21536', '21537', '21538', '21539', '21161', '21162', '21191', '21192', '21215', '21227', '21243', '21273', '21274', '21293', '21294', '21295', '21357', '21358', '21447', '21479', '21480', '21566', '21567', '21678', '21682', '21589', '21592', '21596', '21597', '21680', '21685', '21653', '21648', '21650', '21757', '21756', '21758', '21759', '21798', '21802', '21810', '21812', '21813', '21815', '21817', '21819', '21820', '21874', '21898', '21903', '21904', '21906', '21909', '21879', '21882', '21895', '21901', '21967', '21969', '21980', '21965', '21995', '22010', '22013', '22016', '22022', '22025', '22030', '22033', '22036', '22067', '22107', '22102', '22100', '22099', '22098', '22097', '22096', '22095', '22094', '22092', '22090', '22101', '22083', '22087', '22089', '22188', '22201', '22205', '22189', '22202', '22206', '22216', '22217', '22219', '22164', '22276', '22006', '22253', '22093', '22298', '22313', '22314', '22315', '22330', '22385', '22386', '22405', '22406', '22412', '22413', '22461', '22462', '22476', '22477', '22480', '22503', '22504', '22506', '22505', '22507', '22565', '22541', '22542', '22543', '22600', '22601', '22602', '22656', '22657', '22658', '22659', '22660', '22628', '22629', '22630', '22558', '22560', '22561', '22562', '22564', '22648', '23033', '23038', '23039', '23040', '23255', '23256', '23257', '23258', '23259', '23260', '23261', '23262', '23263', '23340', '23142', '23143', '23144', '23145', '23151', '23153', '23158', '23160', '23155', '23166', '23185', '23186', '23188', '23189', '23197', '23198', '23199', '23209', '23174', '23175', '23231', '23232', '23233', '23244', '23271', '23272', '23273', '23274', '23275', '23276', '23279', '23287', '23288', '23289', '23285', '23286', '23308', '23321', '23322', '23327', '23307', '23310', '23309', '23167', '23047', '23051', '23058', '23059', '23029', '23337', '23338', '23963', '23968', '23977', '23978', '23987', '23962', '24006', '24007', '24102', '24106', '24107', '24108', '24126', '24131', '24132', '24134', '24390', '24393', '24394', '24320', '24319', '24317', '24318', '24301', '24302', '24304', '24285', '24286', '24293', '24465', '24466', '24469', '24471', '24473', '24474', '24475', '24224', '24225', '24226', '24227', '24332', '24420', '24430', '24499', '24500', '24502', '24503', '24504', '24612', '24613', '24515', '24518', '24524', '24631', '24645', '24646', '24647', '24648', '25043', '25052', '25058', '25060', '25061', '25062', '25068', '25067', '25069', '25081', '25082', '25096', '25097', '25098', '25099', '25110', '25111', '25124', '25123', '25136', '25139', '25140', '25152', '25165', '25172', '25173', '25174', '25183', '25192', '25166', '25194', '25204', '25205', '25218', '25226', '25255', '25260', '25269', '25270', '25271', '25220', '25314', '25330', '25329', '25351', '25352', '25359', '25360', '25367', '25368', '25313', '25371', '25377', '25379', '25443', '25445', '25459', '25460', '25466', '25467', '25469', '25507', '25510', '25516', '25532', '25533', '25534', '25535', '25552', '25564', '25565', '25583', '25584', '25585', '25586', '25698', '25808', '25809', '25821', '25822', '25823', '25837', '25839', '25840', '25856', '25890', '25891', '25892', '25893', '25911', '25912', '25914', '25915', '25916', '25932', '25933', '25951', '25952', '25975', '25977', '25978', '25979', '25980', '25395', '24022', '24019', '24027', '24018', '25410', '25411', '25439', '24051', '24033', '24032', '24044', '24041', '24045', '24192', '24188', '24190', '24204', '24179', '24209', '24150', '24149', '24151', '24143', '24247', '24240', '24256', '24245', '24242', '24268', '24250', '26059', '26060', '26082', '26083', '26084', '26096', '26097', '26042', '26044', '26045', '26127', '26128', '26129', '26130', '26131', '26135', '26136', '26137', '26143', '26144', '26160', '26161', '26175', '26177', '26179', '26197', '26198', '26208', '26209', '26210', '26225', '26226', '26227', '26228', '26115', '26116', '26117', '26126', '26257', '26258', '26259', '26271', '26272', '26294', '26295', '26296', '26297', '26327', '26328', '26329', '26330', '26331', '26365', '26367', '26368', '26369', '26385', '26386', '26387', '26400', '26403', '26404', '26406', '26407', '26525', '26527', '26528', '20705', '20706', '20709', '20708', '20707', '24020', '24122', '26556', '26578', '26579', '26580', '26581', '26582', '26600', '26602', '26603', '26604', '26605', '26612', '26614', '26615', '26616', '26617', '26633', '26634', '26635', '26636', '26637', '26654', '26656', '26658', '26676', '26677', '26678', '26680', '26681', '26682', '26683', '26684', '26685', '26755', '26767', '26768', '26769', '26770', '26705', '26706', '26808', '26809', '26817', '26818', '26819', '26835', '26786', '26865', '26876', '26874', '26881', '26892', '26915', '26922', '26930', '26931', '20749', '20750', '20751', '20795', '20796', '20797', '20798', '20799', '20881', '20882', '26979', '26996', '26997', '27016', '27027', '27032', '27036', '27043', '27044', '27052', '27053', '27066', '27067', '20816', '20817', '20818', '20819', '20820', '20821', '20822', '20823', '20898', '20899', '20900', '20901', '27083', '27100', '27101', '27102', '20921', '20938', '20962', '20963', '20964', '20965', '20966', '20967', '20968', '20969', '27117', '27118', '27119', '27137', '27138', '27149', '27151', '27153', '27148', '27150', '27152', '27181', '27182', '27183', '27197', '27209', '27210', '27211', '27222', '27223', '27224', '27266', '26732', '26731', '26537', '27461', '27470', '27475', '27476', '28171', '28177', '28183', '28189', '28193', '28199', '28204', '28209', '28217', '28286', '28352', '29027', '29028', '29036', '29037', '29055', '29047', '29052', '29048', '29064', '29065', '29073', '26875', '26843', '26734', '26733', '26730', '26538', '29081', '29082', '29090', '29100', '29101', '29108', '29109', '29123', '29124', '29133', '29134', '29151', '29159', '29160', '29165', '29178', '29179', '29180', '29197', '29200', '29212', '29220', '29221', '29222', '29234', '29247', '29248', '29249', '29250', '29251', '29252', '29270', '29271', '29296', '29297', '29302', '29305', '29317', '29329', '29330', '29336', '29338', '29343', '29356', '29357', '29359', '26901', '26844', '22068', '29411', '29412', '29430', '29431', '29439', '29440', '29417', '29418', '29424', '29425', '29444', '29462', '29463', '29468', '29467', '29476', '29477', '29483', '29492', '29541', '29542', '29498', '29499', '29500', '29501', '29502', '29505', '29508', '29509', '29510', '29511', '29513', '29514', '29515', '29516', '29512', '29518', '29519', '29520', '24279', '26539', '26842', '26873', '29614', '29615', '29616', '29618', '29642', '29644', '29643', '29652', '29692', '29694', '29695', '29697', '29698', '29699', '29700', '29712', '29731', '29736', '30163', '30247', '30102', '30007', '30382', '29896', '29911', '30489', '30177', '29863', '24271', '26540', '26889', '30578', '30579', '30580', '30606', '30647', '30633', '30634', '30640', '30641', '30654', '30655', '30668', '30667', '30685', '30686', '30687', '30723', '30709', '30754', '30755', '30790', '30776', '30777', '30796', '30797', '30798', '30799', '30809', '30841', '30853', '30852', '30851', '30880', '30898', '30909', '30920', '30958', '30959', '30975', '30976', '31002', '31003', '31030', '31021', '31037', '31038', '31081', '31080', '31091', '31090', '31108', '31107', '31106', '31129', '31128', '31127', '31126', '31125', '31124', '31123', '31122', '31163', '31162', '31161', '31160', '31159', '31158', '31157', '31156', '31180', '31179', '31178', '31183', '31184', '31203', '31199', '31198', '31221', '31219', '31233', '31232', '31231', '31230', '31229', '31250', '31255', '31254', '31278', '31274', '31282', '31283', '31284', '31285', '26888', '31311', '31312', '31366', '31367', '31373', '31374', '31382', '31383', '31403', '31411', '31420', '31425', '31435', '31451', '31473', '31474', '31489', '31500', '31526', '31536', '31544', '31556', '31578', '31650', '31654', '31655', '31672', '31673', '31675', '31689', '31693', '31700', '31701', '31713', '31727', '31729', '26659', '26787', '26785', '26788', '26789', '31808', '31809', '31810', '26816', '26854', '25370', '32048', '25424', '25423', '32434', '32443', '26864', '32451', '32445', '32458', '32477', '32487', '32570', '32569', '32492', '32568', '32567', '32505', '32418', '32571', '32044', '32045', '32581', '32584', '32590', '32594', '32595', '32707', '32723', '32724', '32736', '32749', '32751', '32750', '32752', '32755', '32777', '32778', '32779', '32787', '32788', '32789', '32790', '32800', '32801', '32802', '32894', '32895', '32896', '32897', '32898', '32901', '32902', '32903', '32904', '32963', '32965', '32979', '32986', '29487');
```

Table has  4 indexes: id, id_feature_value,     id_product, id_feature;

Query is quite simple  - get all products features that match query - "if client looks  for yellow products - show them".

Question is - How to speed up query?

Comment: Up to my knowledge IN clause is not suitable here. Instead try with Join. Join the sql statement with the above table which is generating the values passed in IN clause.

Comment: What happens if you drop the `id_feature_value = 0 AND...` and drop the single quotes for int keys? If you set an index on `id_product` AND `id_feature_value` and attach the `... AND` after `id_product`. Use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) is the index used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers to this question suggest that the cause is because of the large IN clause. I do not think this is the case. Instead, I think it is a data type issue which is preventing SQL from calculating an efficient query plan.

In your code, the first value of the IN clause shown is not quoted and so will be considered an INT value, the others are quoted and so will be treated as strings. Therefore I think SQL is doing an IMPLICIT conversion of your column 'id_product' and this then wrecks the [sargability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) of the WHERE clause. I think adding quotes to the first value in your list of constants will improve performance significantly.

Converting the IN clause to a temporary table will solve the issue, by accident, because it corrects the mismatch in the data types.

This question has tags for MYSQL and SQL Server. My investigation was on SQL Server 2016 and so may not apply to other environments.

Comment: Simple but perfect.  From 13s to 0,2s! Excellet!

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

A where in clause like your with so many argument is slow .. and if the number  of elemets is too high  you have error

if you can you should create a table populated with these value and join with you main query

```
create table my_temp_product (
   `id_product`  varchar(20)
) 

insert into my_temp_product 
value 
( '0'), 
('20924'),
('20950'), 
....
.... 
('29487');
```

or if the value are result from a select you can use create table by select  like this

```
create table my_temp_product 
select your_product_id  as id_product
from your_table;
```

and then

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` 
 FROM `product_to_features` AS `product_to_feature` 
 INNER JOIN  my_temp_product on  `product_to_feature`.`id_product` = my_temp_product. `id_product`
 WHERE `product_to_feature`.`id_feature_value` = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN-clause will be translated to something like `id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3 ...`

It should be faster to fill a table with your values and call for an index based and type safe `INNER JOIN`.

If you pass over the ID-List you might think about `CREATE TYPE` to create a *table-valued-parameter*. Such a parameter can be passed into a SQL statements as one single parameter, but internally you can use it just if it was a table.

If the ID-List can be created within your database out of a client's choice (*client looks for yellow products*), it might be better to pass the clients choice rather than the pre-prepared list of IDs. An inlined (*ad-hoc*) query should perform much better...